# Native VPN Client not Connecting with IKEv2

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to connect to an IKEv2-based VPN using the native client in OS X High Sierra (10.13), but am seeing on both the client (Mac) and the server (Linux) that **no packets are being sent between the Mac and the VPN host at all**.

Console shows this message during the connection attempt:

```
-[NESMPluginRegistry copyAppIn:266  Failed to find the VPN app for plugin type com.apple.neplugin.IKEv2
```

Googling for this error only yields results like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/928345/cant-connect-mac-to-azure-vpn-via-ikev2) which shows packets being exchanged, whereas in this case they are not.

#### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open Settings -> Network
2. Create new VPN via "+"
3. Set type to IKEv2
4. Input Server Address and Remote ID
5. Select any settings in Authentication Settings (it does not matter)
6. Inspect packets bound for VPN gateway:

   ```
   sudo tcpdump -nvv dst vpn.example.com
   ```
7. Connect VPN
8. Observe that the output of `tcpdump` is empty
9. Now leave `tcpdump` running and create a similar VPN except with one of the alternative VPN types (L2TP over IPSec or Cisco IPSec)
10. Observe that `tcpdump` shows outbound packets when the non-IKEv2 VPN is attempting to connect